# isset() returning nothing for NULL

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, if-statement

I have written this php code

```
//check if user has active plan and search keyword is not empty
    if (!empty($request['advertisername']) && ($userSubscriptionType == env('AMEMBER_STD_PLAN_CODE') || $userSubscriptionType == env('AMEMBER_PRE_PLAN_CODE'))) {
        $advertisername = 'LOWER(post_owner) like "%' . strtolower($request["advertisername"]) . '%"';
    } else {
        //if search keyword is null, means page is loaded for first time
        if (!isset($request['advertisername'])) {
            $advertisername = "true";
        } else {//if search keyword is not null, and user has not active plan
            $response->code = 400;
            $response->msg = "Permission issues";
            $response->data = "";
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

Here `$request['advertisername']=null` coming from fronend. So this condition will be true `if (!isset($request['advertisername'])) {`. But unfortunately it's always going to last else block.

If i save `$request['advertisername']` in a variable like this. Then this condition `if (!isset($advertiserName)) {` becomes true.

```
//check if user has active plan and search keyword is not empty
if (!empty($request['advertisername']) && ($userSubscriptionType == env('AMEMBER_STD_PLAN_CODE') || $userSubscriptionType == env('AMEMBER_PRE_PLAN_CODE'))) {
    $advertisername = 'LOWER(post_owner) like "%' . strtolower($request["advertisername"]) . '%"';
} else {
    //if search keyword is null, means page is loaded for first time
    $advertiserName=$request['advertisername'];
    if (!isset($advertiserName)) {
        $advertisername = "true";
    } else {//if search keyword is not null, and user has not active plan
        $response->code = 400;
        $response->msg = "Permission issues";
        $response->data = "";
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

I checked the condition via var_dump(). Anyone can explain why it is happening?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour for isset. Return false if not set or NULL, you could try setting it to false instead?

Comment: @pmk nope, isset will return false if the var is set but null. it's on the man page http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `is_null()` instead of `!isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_key_exists() instead:

```
if (!array_key_exists('advertisername', $request)) {
```

Please note the PHP manual for isset() says:

```
isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way would be to check if the variable is not empty as it checks both isset and null

```
eg if(!empty($your_variable) {    /** your code here **/   }
```